# Problem EA 13.2 from David Williams' Probability with Martingales

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am stuck trying to solve this problem from Williams' Probability with Martingales:
[image: Problem from Williams' Probability with Martingales]

My attempt:

$E(X_n) = E(e^{aS_n - bn})$

$= e^{-bn}E(e^{aS_n})$ (because $e^{-bn}$ is not random)

$= e^{-bn}E(e^{a\xi_1}e^{a\xi_2}...e^{a\xi_n})$ (by definition of $S_n$)

$= e^{-bn}E(e^{a\xi_1})E(e^{a\xi_2})...E(e^{a\xi_n})$ (independence)

$= e^{-bn} (e^{1/2 a^2})^n $ (using the formula in the problem statement)

$= e^{n(1/2a^2 - b)}$.

Now this goes to $0$ iff $1/2a^2 - b < 0$, and goes to $\infty$ if $1/2a^2 - b > 0$.

I am assuming $X_n \rightarrow 0 , a.s. \iff E(X_n) \rightarrow 0$ because $X_n \geq 0$

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is *not* true even for non-negative sequences of random variables that the almost sure convergence to $0$ is equivalent to the convergence of the expectation to $0$. (and this example shows is for an appropriate choice of $a$ and $b$)

For the convergence in $\mathbb L^r$, follow the approach you suggested.

For the almost sure convergence, you can use the strong law of large numbers.